# Can't install speechkit for python 3.11.4

Tags: python-3.x, build, grpc, speechkit

I can't understand what the problem is.
I installed vs_BuildTools, C++ development,
wrote in terminal: pip install grpcio, pip install grpcio-tools, python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools==64.0.2, pip install --upgrade pip, pip install wheel, pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

updated python to 3.11.4.
I have Windows 10 22H2, laptop with i7 11800h, 16GB RAM,
PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-223.8836.43, built on March 10, 2023

Looked at similar errors here as well, but it didn't help

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> pip install speechkit
Collecting speechkit
Using cached speechkit-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting boto3 (from speechkit)
Obtaining dependency information for boto3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/87/92592a5aa3eafcebd37117d4d03eef8fd922184813532f743ca607bfb28c/boto3-1.28.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
Using cached boto3-1.28.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio-tools>=1.39.0 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (1.56.0)
Collecting protobuf~=3.19.6 (from speechkit)
Using cached protobuf-3.19.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt>=2.1.0 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (2.7.0)
Collecting cryptography (from speechkit)
Obtaining dependency information for cryptography from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/14/fa7f51806a6204a8534728239c3d5b7f5fee219ccf48ca089d03b72f7573/cryptography-41.0.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata
Using cached cryptography-41.0.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of grpcio-tools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting grpcio-tools>=1.39.0 (from speechkit)
Obtaining dependency information for grpcio-tools>=1.39.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/51/f0dafdcd7e921a7f794fb0fbdf7f17d28447d9658bc70d7920fe248767bd/grpcio_tools-1.54.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.54.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.54.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)
Obtaining dependency information for grpcio-tools>=1.39.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/36/2b2a45b2fa29f821f875630b45c72cf2c400c064367285875d737cbf9a7d/grpcio_tools-1.53.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.53.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.53.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.51.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.51.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.50.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of grpcio-tools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Using cached grpcio_tools-1.49.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Using cached grpcio-tools-1.48.2.tar.gz (2.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.48.2 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from grpcio-tools>=1.39.0->speechkit) (1.56.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from grpcio-tools>=1.39.0->speechkit) (65.5.0)
Collecting botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.3 (from boto3->speechkit)
Obtaining dependency information for botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/f0/5755508b3305534cd4cf2a8a82bbbe42ee9d66fd2688be5ff3dfb85e9a99/botocore-1.31.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
Using cached botocore-1.31.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from boto3->speechkit) (1.0.1)
Collecting s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 (from boto3->speechkit)
Using cached s3transfer-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography->speechkit)
Using cached cffi-1.15.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (1.26.16)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (2023.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.3->boto3->speechkit) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography->speechkit) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.3->boto3->speechkit) (1.16.0)
Using cached boto3-1.28.3-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
Using cached cryptography-41.0.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
Using cached botocore-1.31.3-py3-none-any.whl (11.0 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio-tools
Building wheel for grpcio-tools (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Building wheel for grpcio-tools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[123 lines of output]
>       <string>:30: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools
copying grpc_tools\command.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools
copying grpc_tools\protoc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools
copying grpc_tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\wrappers.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\type.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\timestamp.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\struct.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\source_context.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\field_mask.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\empty.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\duration.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\descriptor.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler\plugin.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\api.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\any.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
running build_ext
building 'grpc_tools._protoc_compiler' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\grpc_root
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\grpc_root\src
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\grpc_tools
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\cpp
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\csharp
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\java
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\js
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\objectivec
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\php
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\python
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\ruby
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\io
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util\internal
>       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\protobuf\src "-ID:\Program Files\Python\include" "-ID:\Program Files\Python\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.obj -std=c++14 /MT
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9025: ЇҐаҐ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "/MD" ­  "/MT"
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9002: Їа®ЇгбЄ ­ҐЁ§ўҐбв­®Ј® Ї а ¬Ґва  "-std=c++14"
python_generator.cc
grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: Ё­ЁжЁ «Ё§ жЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ Ё§ "size_t" ў "int"; ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: Ё­ЁжЁ «Ё§ жЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ Ё§ "size_t" ў "const int"; ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(852): warning C4267:  аЈг¬Ґ­в: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ Ё§ "size_t" ў "int"; ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: Ё­ЁжЁ «Ё§ жЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ Ё§ "size_t" ў "int"; ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: Ё­ЁжЁ «Ё§ жЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ Ё§ "size_t" ў "const int"; ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
>       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\protobuf\src "-ID:\Program Files\Python\include" "-ID:\Program Files\Python\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.obj -std=c++14 /MT
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9025: ЇҐаҐ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "/MD" ­  "/MT"
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9002: Їа®ЇгбЄ ­ҐЁ§ўҐбв­®Ј® Ї а ¬Ґва  "-std=c++14"
_protoc_compiler.cpp
D:\Program Files\Python\include\pyconfig.h(113): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: Ё§¬Ґ­Ґ­ЁҐ ¬ Єа®®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп
D:\Program Files\Python\include\pyconfig.h(113): note: "MS_WIN64" а ­ҐҐ ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ ў Є®¬ ­¤­®© бва®ЄҐ
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(2110): warning C4244:  аЈг¬Ґ­в: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ "Py_ssize_t" ў "int", ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8356): error C2027: ЁбЇ®«м§®ў ­ЁҐ ­Ґ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­­®Ј® вЁЇ  "_frame"
D:\Program Files\Python\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_frame"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9155): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9155): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9169): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9171): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9185): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9187): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9188): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9190): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9211): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9213): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9214): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9216): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9440): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9442): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9443): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9445): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9522): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9525): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9526): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9530): error C2027: ЁбЇ®«м§®ў ­ЁҐ ­Ґ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­­®Ј® вЁЇ  "_frame"
D:\Program Files\Python\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_frame"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9561): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9567): error C2027: ЁбЇ®«м§®ў ­ЁҐ ­Ґ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­­®Ј® вЁЇ  "_frame"
D:\Program Files\Python\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_frame"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9873): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9875): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10122): error C2039: "exc_type": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10124): error C2039: "exc_traceback": ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_err_stackitem".
D:\Program Files\Python\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_err_stackitem"
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio-tools
Failed to build grpcio-tools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for grpcio-tools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with Python 3.11, can you try install it with Python 3.10?